# Vertical table output

Tags: php

I have this php code:

```
foreach($output as $row) {      

    $table.="<tr>";
    foreach($row as $column) {
        $table .="<td>";
        $values = implode(",",$column);
        $table .= count($column);   
        $table .="</td>";
    }
    $table.="</tr>";    
}
    
$table.="</table>";
    
echo $table;
```

This code gives me the results as an horizontal output.
[Horizontal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaWZN.png)

But I need it in vertical position. Like this:

[Vertical table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ajYf.png)

Is it possible to get this result with a simple change?

*Note: I couldn't change the direction of the numbers in the second image.*

There are more than a single row, so the desired table should be something like this:

[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNjkv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one number per row, it should work by moving the `tr`-pairs inside the loop:

```
foreach($row as $column) {
    $table .="<tr><td>";
    $values = implode(",",$column);
    $table .= count($column);   
    $table .="</td></tr>";
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to remove your current `$table .= "<tr>";` and `$table .= "</tr>";` lines.

If you only want the data in one column, you don't really need to use tables. You could just echo the number in div's instead.

Comment: all table rows are lined up in a single column. I need them vertical but still they should be in different columns. in the example above, i gave a single table row, but there are more obviously. how can i make them in different columns?

Comment: @Mat - That's something you should have mentioned from the start. It's pretty obvious that we won't be able to give you the correct guidance if we don't know what the _actually_ expected result is.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply include the `<tr>` inside the `foreach` loop :

```php
foreach($output as $row) {      

    foreach($row as $column) {
        $table.="<tr>";
        $table .="<td>";
        $values = implode(",",$column);
        $table .= count($column);   
        $table .="</td>";
        $table.="</tr>";    
    }
}
    
$table.="</table>";
    
echo $table;
```